# Simple graph equation help

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to take a mock exam and this is one of the questions:

[image]

It is asking me for the equation of the graph. It gives me the following options:

```
 y = 2x - 3 
 y = ½x + 2 
 x = 2y + ½ 
 x = 2y + 3
```

In my mind, none of these answers are correct. It starts at two and for every 1Y you get two X's so I thought it would be this:

```
y = 2x + 2
```

Have I gone wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the graph is not vertical, it can be expressed by the equation $$y = a*x+b$$

Point (0, 2) is on your graph. Therefore

$$2 = a*0 + b$$

Point (2, 3) is also on your graph. Therefore

$$3 = a*2 + b$$

From the first equation, we have $b = 2$. Substitute in the second and you get

$$3 = 2a + 2$$

Therefore, $a$ is $1/2$

The sought equation is

$$y = ½x + 2 $$

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to substitute two points from the given graph into the equations given below.

Take $(0,2)$ and $(10,7)$ and substitute them. As you can see from the options $y=2$ if $x=0$ only in the second equation. Now substitute $(10,7)$ and you will find that it also satisfies. Hence given equation is the second equation.

If your exam is a descriptive one, you can follow the long approach of finding the equation of line.